# What's the passcode?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, story, password

One morning, as you wake up, you feel something on your face: It's a letter. As you take it off your face to read it, You fall off your bed. Uurrrgh, you say and stand up. The letter says: `&$t |* }p|t` Hmmm. Seems angry. `Meet me at 8th and main st. behind the post office in half an hour. Be there.  From Yout Ried.` Ok, you think.

---

Once you arrive, you head into a room and the door slams shut. You try it but it's locked.  On the floor you see a "clue". 
[image: clue]

On the wall you read:

> Say the code and escape. You have 3 tries.

Just beneath that you read:

> `wco ard_q'r uigv wywqwxx wwv kmill, z xvhqigx. rvczym, _h_l nrz. ohlnmv lq: smlvvg_`

Good Luck!

HINT 1

> The angry message isn't really angry...

HINT 2

> The rulebook for Kandoodle might be of help...

HINT 3

> What you can decrypt from the clue will fill the blank spaces on the message on the wall.

HINT 4

> If you can't figure out what the letter means, look up rot13 cyrptii and fiddle with settings.

Comment: Umm... My picture is upside down.

Comment: Is the word "mourning" intentional??

Comment: Is that purposeful or did it just happened? :)

Comment: It just happened Oops @Kevin L and @ QuantumTwinkie

Comment: Ooh, I have one of those puzzle thingies!

Comment: @u_ndefined why fix it? In my opinion, it adds to the puzzle :)

Comment: The picture almost appears to read “clue” (right side up)

Comment: @tyobrien It's supposed to read clue

Comment: I thought I’d mention it as it may not be obvious to everyone. Is that an important part of the puzzle?

Comment: @tyobrien The "clue" is needed. So yes.

Comment: Okay your modification has made it more obvious

Comment: Observation, it seems that fact that "wco ard_q'r uigv wywqwxx wwv kmill z xvhqigx. rvczym, _h_l nrz. ohlnmv lq: smlvvg_" is not included in the quote "Say the code and escape. You have 3 tries." possibly implies that it's not actually written on the wall at all.

Comment: @llRawCodell Ill fix that it is written on the wall

Comment: How correct is the grammar in the message? I don't want to miss something because I'd expect a comma that is actually missing..

Comment: @Carley it should be good now. The punctuation isn't really nessacary though.

Comment: I haven't successfully used the &$t |* }p|t' in my deciphering efforts. Not sure if it's regex or what. Another clue would be awesome, unless you think it's too easy as-is.

Comment: @carley in a week I'll add a new clue.

Comment: Can't you just call management to unlock your door? Or break the door open? Or break the glass (though depending on where you lived you might get fine). Or call the police about how @YoutRied got a letter on my face (kinda suspicious) and possibly broke into my house?

Comment: @north what glass? The door is impenetrable and your phone is being repaired. Plus, it's to late to call about the letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Hint 4, the angry letter translates into -

> Use My Name, the letter was from Yout Ried, so maybe use that name. Use it where though, not sure.

Using Hint 2, the clue translates to-

> IAFH , these are the actual letters written there, according to the rule book.

so the writing in the wall is -

> "wco ardiq'r uigv wywqwxx wwv kmill, z xvhqigx. rvczym, ahfl nrz. ohlnmv lq: smlvvgh." 
>  Which using youtried as key translates into: 
> you haven't gone outside for hours, i presume. anyway, good job. answer is: essence. 
> [done with vigenere cipher of variant Beaufort ]

Finally the passcode is:

> Essence

Comment: Yes that's correct so far, try and continue.

Comment: check the edit now.

Comment: Wow, good job! that is correct.

Comment: the final hint was really helpful.. didn't know about it before..